# Combine two vuejs filters in a different way

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript-vue

I know we can combine vuejs filters sequentially as in `"123 | f1 | f2"` I was wondering if it was possible in another way too.

I have this:

```
<label :text="'icon-credit-card' | iconmap" />
<label :text="'balance {balance}$' | textmap(balance) | localize_digits" />
```

Can I combine these in one label to get something like:

```
<label :text="('icon-credit-card' | iconmap) + ('balance {balance}$' | textmap(balance) | localize_digits)" />
```

Or:

```
<label>
  {{ icon-credit-card | iconmap }}
  {{ balance {balance}$ | textmap(balance) | localize_digits}}
</label>
```

Comment: have you tried a minimal example? like just return a text for the filter or something?

Comment: @PrikeshSavla can you elaborate?

Comment: i dont think they would run parallely, you might have to write a filter to do that for you

Comment: @PrikeshSavla I editted my question

Comment: the OR option should totally be possible